# All R packages such as dplyr, tidyverse, colourpicker, etc. suddenly have error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have R library updated to 4.1 a whie ago and these library were workig properly and suddenly they stopped working.

```
library(shiny)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
> library(dashboardthemes)
WARNING: the 'dashboardthemes' package is no longer being maintained as of version 1.1.6, and will eventually be removed from CRAN. It is recommended that users switch over to the 'bslib' or 'fresh' theming packages available on CRAN.
> library(shinyWidgets)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shinyWidgets’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
> library(shinyjs)
You can use shinyjs to call your own JavaScript functions:
    https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/extend

Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

    removeClass, show

> library(colourpicker)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘colourpicker’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
> library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.6.0 is required
> library(DT)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DT’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
> library (reshape2)
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required
> library(rlang)
```

I tried to remove them and reinstall them and also tried to update the packages but in vain. Can anybody suggest what I should do here?
Thanks

Comment: Some package update introduced a version conflict. Unfortunately this happens. Restart your R session and update the offending packages (in this case, ‘vctrs’ and ‘htmltools’). And when restarting R make sure it doesn’t reload an older session (i.e. don’t save `.RData`).

Comment: The problem is that some package has been updated, and it requires newer versions of `htmltools` and `vctrs`.  Start a new session, run `sessionInfo()` to make sure those are not loaded, then run `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` and update everything consistently.